# Passing the value of a sub-array into CharCodeAt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Essentially I am working on this [coding challenge](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/caesars-cipher#) on FreeCodeCamp. The start of the challenge mentions this to start with...

> A common modern use is the ROT13 cipher, where the values of the
>   letters are shifted by 13 places. Thus 'A' ↔ 'N', 'B' ↔ 'O' and so on.
>
> Write a function which takes a ROT13 encoded string as input and
>   returns a decoded string.

So far I have passed the string to an array, with each part of the string in its own array (a sub-array). From there I figure I would use a loop to go through each character in the string (in each sub-array) and pass the CharCodeAt method to each one.

My problem lies with passing each individual character to go through CharCodeAt.

This is a part of the total function which follows below:

To me this makes sense, as I 'am passing each sub-array value in a variable

```
var foo = container[i][k];


// var output = container.map(function mapHandler(){foo.charCodeAt(k)});



function rot13(str){ 
   var container,  j = 0;
    while(j <= str.length - 1){
       container = str.split(' ');
       j++;
    }

  for(var i = 0; i < container.length; i++){

  for(var k = 0; k < container[i].length; k++){
           var foo = container[i][k];

           var map = Array.prototype.map;
           var output = map.call(foo, function(x){ return x.charCodeAt(k);});

           // var output = container.map(function mapHandler(){foo.charCodeAt(k)});
           // output.charCodeAt(k);

   }

}

    return output;

}

rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC") should decode to "FREE CODE CAMP"
```

Could anyone just help get to this point? I don't want the whole solution!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using `str.split('');` (no space)... you'll get an array containing every character, including spaces, then you won't need more than one loop.

Comment: Um... why are you referencing `container` before it has been defined?

Comment: see of issues here: https://jsbin.com/mivepeh/2/edit?js,console

Comment: The while loop currently just keeps reassigning the split string to `container`

Answer (score 0):

You can turn a string into array of single letters by splitting it with an empty string:

```
var arr = str.split("")
```

Then you can use for example [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to change each letter into decoded one:

```
var decoded = arr.map(x=> {
  // decode x
})
```